# VMware Fusion taking too long to expand disk?

Tags: vmware

I'm running Windows 10 Home in a VM under VMware Fusion 8.5.3 on macOS Sierra 10.12.2. Machine is MacBook Pro (15", Late 2016).

I shut down the Windows guest, and through its settings, attempted to expand the disk from 60GB to 150GB. I have 300GB+ available on the host.

So far, this is what I've been looking at for about 20 minutes:
[image]

How much longer should I wait before giving up? And, if I must give up, what can I do to have the best possible chance that my guest vm isn't totally hosed?

Comment: You patience ought probably to be in direct proportion to the date since your last backup.

Comment: What was the result. Same deal here, thing has been hanging for a while.

Comment: Same here ... Hanging up ... But I will wait and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to this is: **just wait**.

However, there is a little caveat, if you want that this transition is really successfully and fast you need to temporary turn on Time Machine backup.

Comment: What does Time Machine backup have to do with expanding the disk for the VM?

Comment: It somehow interfere with backup disk operation service and vm ware disk expansion service ... Quite logical to me ...

Comment: As soon as I turned off Time Machine my resize completed instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Same here with Fusion 8.5.8 and macOS 10.13.2. I expanded a VM from 60 to 80 GB, progress bar stayed there for 30 minutes. Then it was done, all good.